# Recent sci-fi novel: ancient spaceship found in South America

Tags: story-identification

I read a sci-fi novel about a group of scientists who find an ancient spaceship in South America, Bolivia I believe, and at the end a signal is sent out by the ship into deep space. It is a fairly recently written book and I would like to read it again or see if a sequel was written.
It went into detail about how the aliens tried to teach the humans, but I think that a bacteria killed them in the end.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could it be [*The Martian Inca*](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1871429.The_Martian_Inca)?

Comment: Did the aliens leave behind a humanoid female child?

Comment: no alien Child,   the ancient aliens died from bacteria, but the ship sent out a signal before it was destroyed,   it ended with the crew and government wondering who the signal was going to.